# Flask order records by 2 children columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
child1Id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('child1.id'))
child1 = db.relationship("Child1Model", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[child1Id])
child2Id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('child2.id'))
child2 = db.relationship("Child2Model", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[child2Id])
child3Id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('child3.id'))
child3 = db.relationship("Child3Model", uselist=False, foreign_keys=[child3Id])
```

All 3 children tables have an id and a name, among other columns. For sorting the parent based on child1's name, I defined the following hybrid property and expression:

```
@hybrid_property
def child1Name(self):
    return self.child1.name

@child1Name.expression
def child1Name(cls):
    return select([Child1Model.name]).where(Child1Model.id == cls.child1Id).as_scalar()
```

When I call `Parent.query.order_by(Parent.child1Name).all()`, the expression is working as expected.

Now, for child2 and child3, only one of them will be set, so when a parent entity have child2 set, child3 is None and viceversa. I want to sort the parent based on the names of child2 and child3, so that, for example, if I have a parent entity with child2 set, and child2.name = "B" and another parent with child3 set and child3.name = "A", the second parent should be returned first. I tried to define the following hybrid property:

```
@hybrid_property
def child2Or3Name(self):
    if self.child2Id is not None:
        return self.child2.name
    return self.child3.name

@child2Or3Name.expression
def child2Or3Name(cls):
    if cls.child2Id is not None:
        return select([Child2Model.name]).where(Child2Model.id == cls.child2Id).as_scalar()
    return select([Child3Model.name]).where(Child3Model.id == cls.child3Id).as_scalar()
```

But when I call `Parent.query.order_by(Parent.child2Or3Name).all()` , the data is returned, but not in the correct order. How should I define the hybrid property and its expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, the expression should look like:

```
@child2Or3Name.expression
def child2Or3Name(cls):
    s1 = select([Child2Model.name]).where(Child2Model.id == cls.child2Id)
    s2 = select([Child3Model.name]).where(Child3Model.id == cls.child3Id)
    return s1.union_all(s2).as_scalar()
```